# Need help regarding "llc calib -s" command

Tags: command-line, drivers

I am trying to install llc-drivers for an evaluation kit. A new calibration file for VERA-P1 evaluation kit is available.
It needs to be loaded with the following llc command:

```
llc calib -s < vera-p17x-00a-00.conf
```

But the following error comes:

```
llc: Unknown command line argument '-s'.  Try: 'llc --help'

llc: Did you mean '-I'?
```

How to resolve this error? Thanks

Comment: You are asked to do a `llc --help`. So does that show that there is an option `-s`? If not don't use it. edit: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/llc-6.0.1.html does not show it so what do you use it?

Comment: Ok. I typed this 'llc calib < vera-p17x-00a-00.conf' and the following comes:  'llc: error: llc: calib: error: Could not open input file: No such file or directory'. but the file is already there. I just want to load the file which i am unable to do it. The command in my main question is specified in user guide (@Rinzwind)